# Convert Pan/Tilt angles to XYZ in Three.js using Quaternion?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a legacy flash project I'm converting to Three.js, and need to know how to convert the existing pan/tilt values to 3d coordinates,i.e. x,y,z

For an example, I have a hotspot

```
        var bubble = {
        name : 'hotspot',
        pan : 31,
        tilt : 0,
        distance : 2000
        };
```

Placed in the scene, these coordinates are approx the correct position:

```
        text.position.x = -100;
        text.position.z = 200;
        text.position.y = 0;
```

I'm trying to work out how to convert these values. The distance of 2000 is equivilent to 512 in the Three.js version.

I've been trying make the numbers work using http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion however Math is not my strongpoint.

Any help greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I've got a little bit closer with

```
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), Math.radians(bubble.tilt) );
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), Math.radians(bubble.pan) );
    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ), Math.radians(bubble.distance/2) );

    text.position.x = quaternion.x * 512;
    text.position.z = quaternion.z * 512;
    text.position.y = quaternion.y * 512;
```

However I still can't get them to position properly..

Here's the test
http://gms.beektest.co/resources/beek3/eg.html

They should be arranged more like this http://beek.co/g218

Comment: See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2.html and look at `render()`. It shows how to convert from lat/lon coordinates to Cartesian coordinates. With some experimentation, you should be able to figure out how `pan` and `tilt` relate to `lon` and `lat`. Also, consider using Sprite text labels or CSS text, instead of 3D text in your case.

Comment: Thanks WestLangley. Will do. So you think Quaternion is not the tree I should be barking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original attempt worked

```
        var distance = bubble.distance/4;
        var pr = Math.radians(-1 * bubble.pan );
        var tr = Math.radians( bubble.tilt );

        text.position.x = distance * Math.cos(pr) * Math.cos(tr);
        text.position.y = distance * Math.sin(tr);
        text.position.z = distance * Math.sin(pr) * Math.cos(tr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the Quaternion class

```
var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), tilt );
quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 ), pan );
text.position.x = quaternion.x;
text.position.y = quaternion.y;
text.position.z = quaternion.z;
```

Pseudo code.. untested.

Comment: This helps, but doesn't solve it. They're stacking up next to each other and not spreading out relating to their pans.